How to use Reactor Kafka KafkaSender API to send messages to two different topics (situated in two different Kafka clusters)?
I am trying to send messages to two different kafka topics using the KafkaSender of Reactor Kafka.
By two different kafka topics, I mean:
There is a topic called "first_topic" in cluster kafka-first-broker.com:9092
Then, there is another topic called "another_topic", in another cluster, not the same as above, called kafka-another-broker-not-the-same-as-above.com:9093
However, it seems the send method of reactor kafka only supports one destination
I tried using the send method with a comma-separated list of (two topics)
SenderRecord.create(new ProducerRecord<>("first_topic,another_topic", null, mymessage), mymessage)

I was expecting this to be sent to two different topics, but it can only be sent to one.
How can I leverage Reactor Kafka KafkaSender API to send messages to two different topics situated in two different Kafka clusters?

There's only one ProducerConfig shared across the senders. There's only one cluster represented per ProducerConfig
You'll need to construct a new instance of both, first.

Thank you, indeed, it seems it needs two different KafkaSenders beans
